# Creating dynamic table from javascript array considering rowspans

Tags: javascript, html

I want to dynamically create a table from JSON object and I will have to consider the rowspans.

So my array is something like below and the table will then display Id, Name, Age in a td and hobbies, skills, language will be row spanned.

My table with the below array will then look like
[image: Click here to view the table]

```js
var myArr = [{
    "Id": 1,
    "Name": 'Ken',
    "Age": '30',
    "Hobbies": [{
      'HobbyId': 1,
      'HobbyName': 'Swimming'
    }, {
      'HobbyId': 2,
      'HobbyName': 'Reading'
    }],
    "Skills": [{
      'SkillId': 1,
      'SkillName': 'PHP'
    }, {
      'SkillId': 2,
      'SkillName': 'MySQL'
    }],
    "Language": [{
      'LangId': 2,
      'LangName': 'English'
    }, {
      'LangId': 3,
      'LangName': 'Chinese'
    }]
  },
  {
    "Id": 2,
    "Name": 'Mike',
    "Age": '20',
    "Hobbies": [],
    "Skills": [],
    "Language": []
  },
  {
    "Id": 3,
    "Name": 'Charlie',
    "Age": '25',
    "Hobbies": [{
      'HobbyId': 5,
      'HobbyName': 'Dance'
    }, {
      'HobbyId': 6,
      'HobbyName': 'Sing'
    }, {
      'HobbyId': 7,
      'HobbyName': 'Writing'
    }],
    "Skills": [],
    "Language": [{
      'Id': 7,
      'Name': 'English'
    }]
  }
]
```

If there's a possible way to look like the table in the image with some css we can consider that too.

This is what I tried.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var myArr = [{
      "Id": 1,
      "Name": 'Ken',
      "Age": '30',
      "Hobbies": [{
        'HobbyId': 1,
        'HobbyName': 'Swimming'
      }, {
        'HobbyId': 2,
        'HobbyName': 'Reading'
      }],
      "Skills": [{
        'SkillId': 1,
        'SkillName': 'PHP'
      }, {
        'SkillId': 2,
        'SkillName': 'MySQL'
      }],
      "Language": [{
        'LangId': 2,
        'LangName': 'English'
      }, {
        'LangId': 3,
        'LangName': 'Chinese'
      }]
    },
    {
      "Id": 2,
      "Name": 'Mike',
      "Age": '20',
      "Hobbies": [],
      "Skills": [],
      "Language": []
    },
    {
      "Id": 3,
      "Name": 'Charlie',
      "Age": '25',
      "Hobbies": [{
        'HobbyId': 5,
        'HobbyName': 'Dance'
      }, {
        'HobbyId': 6,
        'HobbyName': 'Sing'
      }, {
        'HobbyId': 7,
        'HobbyName': 'Writing'
      }],
      "Skills": [],
      "Language": [{
        'Id': 7,
        'Name': 'English'
      }]
    }
  ];


  var table = "<table border=1>";
  for (var i = 0; i < myArr.length; i++) {
    var arrHobies = myArr[i]['Hobbies'];
    var arrSkills = myArr[i]['Skills'];
    var arrLanguage = myArr[i]['Language'];
    var rowspan = Math.max(arrHobies.length, arrSkills.length, arrLanguage.length);
    console.log(rowspan);
    table += "<tr>";
    table += "<td rowspan=" + rowspan + ">" + myArr[i]['Id'] + "</td>";
    table += "<td rowspan=" + rowspan + ">" + myArr[i]['Name'] + "</td>";
    table += "<td rowspan=" + rowspan + ">" + myArr[i]['Age'] + "</td>";
    console.log(arrHobies);
    for (var j = 0; j < arrHobies.length; j++) {

      if (j == 0) {
        table += "<td>" + arrHobies[j]['HobbyId'] + "</td>";
        table += "<td>" + arrHobies[j]['HobbyName'] + "</td>";
      } else {
        table += "<tr>";
        table += "<td>" + arrHobies[j]['HobbyId'] + "</td>";
        table += "<td>" + arrHobies[j]['HobbyName'] + "</td>";
        //table+="</tr>";

      }
      //table+="</tr>";

    }

    for (var k = 0; k < arrSkills.length; k++) {
      if (k == 0) {
        table += "<td>" + arrSkills[k]['SkillId'] + "</td>";
        table += "<td>" + arrSkills[k]['SkillName'] + "</td>";
      } else {
        // table+="<tr>";
        table += "<td>" + arrSkills[k]['SkillId'] + "</td>";
        table += "<td>" + arrSkills[k]['SkillName'] + "</td>";
        table += "</tr>";

      }
      table += "</tr>";

    }

    table += "</tr>";
  }
  table += "</table>";
  console.info(table);
  $("#myDiv").html(table);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="myDiv"></div>
```

Comment: You could just set your rowspan to something like `Math.max(obj.Hobbies.length, obj.Skills.length, obj.Language.length)`. You should really try something, then come to Stack Overflow when you need help with something specific.

Comment: you just provided the json. What have you tried so far?

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan , I have tried that but its messing up the table.Can you please share in details as what I should do.

Comment: Nope, that's not how Stack Overflow works. We don't just write code for you. I am a consultant though, and would be willing to come to a small fee for my services :). Otherwise, as I mentioned before, [edit] your question to show what you've tried, and I or someone else would be willing to help guide you toward the answer.

Comment: Let me give you some advice. First, start small. Create the table element, then add the headers. I would suggest doing it in javascript for your own learning. Tips: function that could help you: `forEach`

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan added what I have tried for.

Comment: That code won't display anything. You need to append it to the DOM.

Comment: $funcoding I know that, but the issue is the output I am getting is mixing some values at wrong places.

Comment: Is there anyone who can help me out with this.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan, funcoding: Added some code I have tried.

Comment: Yeah, see, you're almost there. You just need to clean up where you're putting the `"<tr>"`. You need to remember that you want to put each hobby at index `j` in the same row as the skill at the same index. My suggestion would be to combine the two inner loops, making check `j < Math.max(arrHobbies.length, arrSkills.length)`, and checking if `arrHobbies[j]` is defined before writing it out (same with `arrSkills`).